# How to plot a spherical spiral in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

This is what I am inputting into *Mathematica*:

```
x[t]==(cos(t))/((0.1^2*t^2)^(1/2))
y[t]==(sin(t))/((0.1^2*t^2)^(1/2))
z[t]==-(0.1t)/((0.1^2*t^2+1)^(1/2))
ParametricPlot3D[{x[t],y[t],z[t]},{t,-30,30}]
```

Comment: Not even close. Both math and Mathematica syntax errors.

Answer (score 6):

There quite a few syntax issues. After correcting those, you can have

```
x = (Cos[t])/((0.1^2*t^2)^(1/2));
y = (Sin[t])/((0.1^2*t^2)^(1/2)) ; 
z = -(0.1 t)/((0.1^2*t^2 + 1)^(1/2));
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {t, -30, 30}]
```

[image]

Or you can do it like this too,

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(Cos[t])/((0.1^2*t^2)^(1/2)), (Sin[t])/((0.1^2*t^2)^(1/2))
 , -(0.1 t)/((0.1^2*t^2 + 1)^(1/2))}, {t, -30, 30}]
```

**Edit**

The [spherical curve parametric equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalSpiral.html) in its general form are combine in one function like this

```
f[a_, t_] := {Cos[t] Cos[ArcTan[a*t]],Sin[t] Cos[ArcTan[a*t]],-Sin[ArcTan[a*t]]};
```

Now plotting for a particular value of the constant `a`,

```
With[{a = 0.1},ParametricPlot3D[f[a, t], {t, -2*Pi/a, 2*Pi/a}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I create this graph to be a full spherical spiral instead of just the top half? ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t]Sin[t/30],Sin[t/30]Sin[t/30],Cos[t/30]},{t,0,30}]

Comment: @AllyCronander Just change `{t,0,30}` to `{t,0,30*2*Pi}` as suggested by march.

Comment: Instead of 30*2 which seems arbitrary, shouldn't you be using 1 radian (I.e. 57.2958)