# Why won't my graph show up?

Tags: plotting

I entered

```
h[x_] := Sqrt[x] + cos x
```

into the system and then entered

```
Plot[h[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

and it's showing up with plot but with no curve plotted. I've tried scaling up and down the area to be shown, but nothing changes. I've also tried re-entering my function into the system and it's not affecting anything. Is there anything else I can try?

#### Edit

I changed my original function to

```
h[x_] := Sqrt[x] + cos[x]
```

and it is still not plotting. I also changed my range to `{x, 0, 2pi}` and that has not affected anything either.

#### Edit 2

I capitalized the c in cosine and it is now plotting the function. Thank you!

Comment: Your definition should be `h[x_] := Sqrt[x] + Cos[x]`. The Wolfram Language is case sensitive and the names of all built-in functions begin with capital letters. And `{x, 0, 2pi}` should be `{x, 0, 2 Pi}`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136864/how-to-plot-a-spherical-spiral-in-mathematica

Comment: To be expicit: h[x_] := Sqrt[x] + Cos[x]; Plot[h[x], {x, -10, 10}] shows the plot fine.

Comment: For the possible duplicate-- That's a 3D graph; I'm graphing in 2D

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I suggest reading https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write Cos[x], not cos x. So, you need to define your function as

```
h[x_] := Sqrt[x] + Cos[x].
```

Besides, since the square root of x is only defined for values of $x \geq 0$ you shouldn't expect something for negative values of x.

Comment: This fixed one problem I had where the NSolve command for this function as equal to zero was actually showing up with an answer and I knew it wasn't supposed to, but the graph is still empty (and I changed my range to 0, 2pi).

Comment: I didn't notice that you had changed the lowercase c to a capital C, but I have now changed that and it is now plotting. Thank you!